# Shuffle Cards and display 10 java applet

Tags: java, loops, random, applet, awt

In this assignment you will use an applet to display images of playing cards. The applet should load a deck of 52 playing card images from the "images" folder that you downloaded. The applet should shuffle the deck (use a random number generator) and display the first 10 cards of the shuffled deck. Display the cards in two rows of five cards each.

My applet works partially, but when I run the applet viewer the display is just the same card ten times. Here is my code:

```
package CTY;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.util.Random;

public class Exercise12 extends Applet {

    Image c1;
    Image c2;
    Image c3;
    Image c4;
    Image c5;
    Image c6;
    Image c7;
    Image c8;
    Image c9;
    Image c10;

    public void init() {
        Random random = new Random();
        String cards[][] = {
                { "cards/c1.gif", "cards/c2.gif", "cards/c3.gif", "cards/c4.gif", "cards/c5.gif", "cards/c6.gif",
                        "cards/c7.gif", "cards/c8.gif", "cards/c9.gif", "cards/c10.gif", "cards/cj.gif",
                        "cards/ck.gif", "cards/cq.gif" },
                { "cards/s1.gif", "cards/s2.gif", "cards/s3.gif", "cards/s4.gif", "cards/s5.gif", "cards/s6.gif",
                        "cards/s7.gif", "cards/s8.gif", "cards/s9.gif", "cards/s10.gif", "cards/sj.gif",
                        "cards/sk.gif", "cards/sq.gif" },
                { "cards/d1.gif", "cards/d2.gif", "cards/d3.gif", "cards/d4.gif", "cards/d5.gif", "cards/d6.gif",
                        "cards/d7.gif", "cards/d8.gif", "cards/d9.gif", "cards/d10.gif", "cards/dj.gif",
                        "cards/dk.gif", "cards/dq.gif" },
                { "cards/h1.gif", "cards/h2.gif", "cards/h3.gif", "cards/h4.gif", "cards/h5.gif", "cards/h6.gif",
                        "cards/h7.gif", "cards/h8.gif", "cards/h9.gif", "cards/h10.gif", "cards/hj.gif",
                        "cards/hk.gif", "cards/hq.gif" } };

        int Card[] = new int[10];
        int Suit[] = new int[10];
        int suit = random.nextInt(4);
        int card = random.nextInt(10);
        boolean newCard = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            while (newCard == false) {
                newCard = true;
                suit = random.nextInt(4);
                card = random.nextInt(13);

                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                    if (Card[j] == card && Suit[j] == suit ) {
                        newCard = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            Card[i] = card;
            Suit[i] = suit;
        }

        c1 = getImage(getDocumentBase(),
                cards[Suit[0]][Card[0]]);
        c2 = getImage(getDocumentBase(),
                cards[Suit[1]][Card[1]]);
        c3 = getImage(getDocumentBase(),
                cards[Suit[2]][Card[2]]);
        c4 = getImage(getDocumentBase(),
                cards[Suit[3]][Card[3]]);
        c5 = getImage(getDocumentBase(),
                cards[Suit[4]][Card[4]]);
        c6 = getImage(getDocumentBase(),
                cards[Suit[5]][Card[5]]);
        c7 = getImage(getDocumentBase(),
                cards[Suit[6]][Card[6]]);
        c8 = getImage(getDocumentBase(),
                cards[Suit[7]][Card[7]]);
        c9 = getImage(getDocumentBase(),
                cards[Suit[8]][Card[8]]);
        c10 = getImage(getDocumentBase(),
                cards[Suit[9]][Card[9]]);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
        graphics.drawImage(c1, 30, 30, this);
        graphics.drawImage(c2, 30, 150, this);
        graphics.drawImage(c3, 120, 30, this);
        graphics.drawImage(c4, 120, 150, this);
        graphics.drawImage(c5, 210, 30, this);
        graphics.drawImage(c6, 210, 150, this);
        graphics.drawImage(c7, 300, 30, this);
        graphics.drawImage(c8, 300, 150, this);
        graphics.drawImage(c9, 390, 30, this);
        graphics.drawImage(c10, 390, 150, this);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT using components in favor of Swing.

Answer (score 2):

Issue with the loop as newCard flag will be true always after one iteration

```
for (int i = 1; i <=10; i++) {
            while (newCard == false) {
                newCard = true;
                suit = random.nextInt(4);
                card = random.nextInt(13);

                for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                    if (Card[j] == card && Suit[j] == suit ) {
                        newCard = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            Card[i] = card;
            Suit[i] = suit;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's your problem:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        while (newCard == false) {
            newCard = true;
            suit = random.nextInt(4);
            card = random.nextInt(13);

            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (Card[j] == card && Suit[j] == suit ) {
                    newCard = false;
                }
            }
        Card[i] = card;
        Suit[j] = suit;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the setup of your loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    while (newCard == false) {
        newCard = true;
        suit = random.nextInt(4);
        card = random.nextInt(13);

        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (Card[j] == card && Suit[j] == suit ) {
                newCard = false;
            }
        }
    }

    Card[i] = card;
    Suit[i] = suit;
}
```

The first time through the while loop `i` is 0 and so it never enters the inner for loop causing newCard to remain true. Because newCard is true it doesn't go through the while loop again and so the variables card and suit never change through the iterations of the outer for loop.

One solution is to set `newCard = false` right before the while loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    newCard = false;
    while (newCard == false) {
        newCard = true;
        suit = random.nextInt(4);
        ...
```

This will ensure it always enters the while loop on each iterations of the outer for loop.